# Approximating a limit of $\cot$ whose argument is close to zero without L'Hospital's Rule

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I was reading something that mentioned $ \cot {\pi \over 648000} \approx {648000 \over \pi}$ since the argument of $\cot$ is close to zero, and it also said this can be derived by the fact that $\lim_{x \to 0} {\tan x \over x} = 1$.

I simplified the problem as whether

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left({1 \over \tan x} - {1 \over x}\right) = 0$$

is true, and thought about it, but couldn't figure out the reasoning.

---

Thank's for a [duplicate suggestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860283/easier-way-to-solve-lim-limits-x-to-0-space-cotx-1-over-x-using-l), I got to know that this could be solved by applying L'Hospital's Rule twice, but I still wanted to figure out a derivation with $\lim_{x \to 0} {\tan x \over x} = 1$ as was written in the thing I read.

Here's what I tried, getting a hint from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/860525/1013455).

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left({1 \over \tan x} - {1 \over x}\right)$$
$$= \lim_{x \to 0} \left({x - \tan x \over x^2} \times {x \over \tan x}\right)$$
$$= \lim_{x \to 0} \left({1 \over x} - {1 \over x} {\tan x \over x}\right)$$

It's really tempting to just replace $\tan x$ with $x$ (which often works to just get an answer) and argue,

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left({1 \over x} - {1 \over x} {\tan x \over x}\right) = \lim_{x \to 0} \left({1 \over x} - {1 \over x}\right) = 0$$

but that involves distributing $\lim_{x \to 0}$ to $\lim_{x \to 0} {1 \over x}$, which I don't think is good mathematical reasoning.

How can I clean up from the last step?

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left({1 \over x} - {1 \over x} {\tan x \over x}\right) = 0$$

Comment: The result can be proved using the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x} {x} =\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x} {x} =1$ but not in the way you have done. In general one can not replace part of an expression with its limit while evaluating limit of the expression. You will need to make use of the inequality $\sin x<x<\tan x$ for $x\in(0,\pi/2)$.

Answer (score 1):

The [Laurent series for the cotangent](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Power_Series_Expansion_for_Cotangent_Function) is
$$
\cot x = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{x }{3}  - \frac{x^3}{45} - \cdots
$$
so for small $x$,
$$
\cot x \approx \frac{1}{x}.
$$